# New User URL not displaying properly

Tags: urlhacking, user-management, user-record, custom-url

I have a requirement to invoke the user creation page to prepopulate some fields. I'm using the following URL:

```
/lightning/o/User/new?defaultFieldValues=LastName={!User.LastName},ProfileId={!User.ProfileId},Department__c={!User.Department__c}
```

The problem with this URL is that it is not redirecting to the whole user creation page but it is displaying a New User popup withh very limited fields. Does any one knows which ons is the URL to the user creation page?
Thanks,

Comment: `defaultFieldValues` with user object takes the `User Profile Page Layouts`, so it shows the fields that are configured in that layout. If you are looking for page in `Manager Users`, it may not work unless there is any other hack around it.

Comment: Hi Brahmaji. Yes, I configured that page layout but still not all the fields can be accessed, like User License, Marketing User, Offline User...I was hoping that there is a way to use Manager Users page.
Also, I'm not able to save the user from that popup, I'm getting an error that doesn't tell me much when I try to save:
"No access to field . Either the field was removed from the entity or access to this field was removed."
Thanks,